# push image element into array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var testArray = [];

var testImage = new Image();
testImage.src = "entities/left.png";
testArray.push({image: testImage, xpos: 100, ypos: 100, width: 100, height: 100});

console.log(testArray.image);
```

The output from the console.log says "undefined", if I log testArray[0] it says "image: img" in the image part. is there a way to push the actual img element into the array?

Comment: You already did it. To access image object use console.log(testArray[0].image);

Comment: You *are* pushing the image in testArray[0].image

Answer (score 1):

You're already accessing that element, through `testArray[0].image`, and that's the only way to access element within an array (index-based). There's not dot notation (e.g. `testArray.image`) for accessing array's entries.

Comment: Happy to be helpful. Remember to mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You have created an array of object, which is correct. Try this
 testArray[0].image

This says that you are accessing image property of your first element of array